# How to get Jfrog Artifactory and Xray versions

Tags: automation, artifactory

I have a task to automate the comparison of current deployed Jfrog Artifactory and Xray version vs latest available.
I tried to find some API or cli command, which will return me the versions, couldnt find any.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the information for Artifactory from the [System Info REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SystemInfo). Search for `artifactory.version` in the long output.

For Xray, you get it from the [Get Version REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-GetVersion).

Comment: Since /api/system requires an admin user, it might be easier to call any other endpoint (like /api/system/ping) and inspect HTTP Server header. This reports Artifactory version, even on failed requests (e.g. status != 200). Works for Artifactory 6.x at least.